# Optimization problems with View using Clustered Index Insert on tempdb on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, view, query-optimization, clustered-index, tempdb

I am creating a Java function that needs to use a SQL query with a lot of joins before doing a full scan of its result. Instead of hard-coding a lot of joins I decided to create a view with this complex query. Then the Java function just uses the following query to get this result:

```
SELECT * FROM VW_####
```

So the program is working fine but I want to make it faster since this `SELECT` command is taking a lot of time. After taking a look on its plan execution plan I created some indexes and made it +-30% faster but I want to make it faster.

The problem is that every operation in the execution plan have cost between 0% and 4% except one operation, a clustered-index insert that has +-50% of the execution cost. I think that the system is using a temporary table to store the view's data, but an index in this view isn't useful for me because I need all rows from it.

So what can I do to optimize that insert in the `CWT_PrimaryKey`? I think that I can't turn off that index because it seems to be part of the SQL Server's internals. I read somewhere that this operation could appear when you use cursors but I think that I am not using (or does the view use it?).

The command to create the view is something simple (no T-SQL, no OPTION, etc) like:

```
create view VW_#### as SELECTS AND JOINS HERE
```

And here is a picture of the problematic part from the execution plan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csH91.jpg

**EDIT: More details:**

Well the query to create the problematic view is a big query that join a lot of tables. Based on a single parameter the Java-Client modifies the query string before creating it. This view represents a "data unit" from a legacy Database migrated to the SQLServer that didn't had any Foreign or Primary Key, so our team choose to follow this strategy. Because of that the view have more than 50 columns and it is made from the join of other seven views.

Main view's query (with a lot of Portuguese words): http://pastebin.com/Jh5vQxzA

The other views (from VW_Sintese1 until VW_Sintese7) are created like this one but without using extra views, they just use joins with the tables that contain the data requested by the main view.

Then the Java Client create a prepared Statement with the query "Select * from VW_Sintese####" and execute it using the function "ExecuteQuery", something like:

```
String query = "Select * from VW_Sintese####";
PreparedStatement ps = myConn.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

And then the program goes on until the end.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: One easy way to optimize might be to select only columns you really need (instead of using `SELECT * ....`) and if that's a small number of columns, try to come up with a **covering index** - a nonclustered index on some column(s) that you use in your `WHERE` clauses, and add additional columns you need from your query as **included columns** to that index.

Comment: Yes, you *are* using cursors. I can tell from that index name. That easily explains the performance problems. Maybe your Java API uses them. Post some Java code, or do some research on this yourself.

Comment: A bit of Java Code posted on the main question.

Comment: Downvote because the question *still* lacks definition and context.  Remove the `ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EN_Nome) as "ID",` and see if that 50% index insert is eliminated.  If yes, that's your problem area.  Then stop using views, don't get so much data back, sort your data in your client.

Answer (score 0):

First: you should post the code of the view along with whatever is using the views because of the rest of this answer.

Second: the definition of a view in SQL Server is later used to substitute in querying.  In other words, you created a view, but since (I'm assuming) it isn't an indexed view, it is the same as writing the original, long SELECT statement.  SQL Server kind of just swaps it out in the DML statement.

From Microsoft's 'Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012':  T-SQL supports the following table expressions: derived tables, common table expressions (CTEs), views, inline table-valued functions.

And a direct quote:

`It’s important to note that, from a performance standpoint, when SQL Server optimizes
queries involving table expressions, it first unnests the table expression’s logic, and therefore interacts with the underlying tables directly. It does not somehow persist the table expression’s result in an internal work table and then interact with that work table. This means that table expressions don’t have a performance side to them—neither good nor
bad—just no side.`

This is a long way of reinforcing the first statement: please include the SQL code in the view and what you're actually using as the `SELECT` statement.  Otherwise, we can't help much :)  Cheers!

**Edit**:  Okay, so you've created a view (no performance gain there) that does 4-5 `LEFT JOIN` on to the main view (again, you're not helping yourself out much here by eliminating rows, etc.).  If there are search arguments you can use to filter down the resultset to fewer rows, you should have those in here.  And lastly, you're ordering all of this at the top, so your query engine will have to get those views, join them up to a massive `SELECT` statement, figure out the correct order, and (I'm guessing here) the result count is HUGE and SQL's db engine is ordering it in some kind of temporary table.

The short answer: get less data (fewer columns and only the rows you need); don't order the results if the resultset is very large, just get the data to the client and then sort it there.

Again, if you want more help, you'll need to post table schemas and index strategies for all tables that are in the query (*including the views that are joined*) and you'll need to include all view definitions (*including the views that are joined*).

Comment: Oh sorry for the late answer, I added more details including some code. Now thinking better maybe this problem could be occuring because of the PreparedStatement's creation parameters.